# C# Generic method calling two different services

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, .net-core

I have the following method, which is to add product using the injected service! It is called inside a static calls hence it is static!

```
public static async Task AddNewProducts(Guid shopId)
{
    var productAService = IoC.Services.GetService<IProductAService>();
    var added = await productAService.AddProduct(shopId);
}
```

It works fine but I need to make it generic so that I can use different services with it.
Something like this!

```
public static async Task AddNewProducts<T>(Guid shopId) 
    where T : IProductAService, IProductBService
{
    var productService = IoC.Services.GetService<T>();
    var added = await productService.AddProduct(shopId);
}
```

However the second methods complains that the AddProduct method is ambiguous, not sure how I can make sure it is calling the right method from the related service!

Comment: Why do you have static methods? Why not just define a regular class, inject your service via constructor injection, and go from there? Why do you need generics at all?

Comment: My assumption (but you've not shared that code for some reason so hard to be certain) is that both `IProductAService` and `IProductBService` define an `AddProduct(Guid shopId)` method. You've told your generic method to only accept something that implements both `IProductAService` AND `IProductBService` so now it doesn't know which of those two you want to call on `productService`.

Comment: @Knoop that's correct, and that is exactly my question! How can I tell it to differentiate two different implementations?

Comment: @user65248 The best bet would be to move the `AddProduct` method into another interface that both of your interfaces would inherit from, then use that interface in the constraint.

Comment: @mason I have simplified the method, it's a big one, generic because I don't want to repeat code ! Static because this is called within a main method of a console application!

Comment: Just because you call it from a main method doesn't mean it has to be static. All you have to do is create an instance. `var myInstance = new MyService(parameters); myInstance.DoSomething(someMoreParameters);`

Comment: If you're thinking generics are the solution, you're probably wrong.

Comment: `var added = await productService.AddProduct(shopId);` by writing this line, you are assuming that both interfaces have `AddProduct` method with exactly the same signature. So there should an interface which is inherited by both interfaces.

Comment: @Moshii that is correct. But would declaring a parent interface resolve the issue!? I think it would still complain!

Comment: The problem is that while you "know" the methods are the same the compiler doesn't know that. By moving the method to a shared parent interface you remove the ambiguity (and with that the ambiguity complaint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2 services need a common interface

```
public interface IProductService
{
    void AddProduct(Guid shopId);
}

public interface IProductAService : IProductService 
{ 
  //specifics to service A
}
public interface IProductBService : IProductService 
{ 
  //specifics to service B
}
```

Then your static, generic method just constrains to the shared interface

```
public static async Task AddNewProducts<TProductService>(Guid shopId) 
                               where TProductService : IProductService
{
   var productService = IoC.Services.GetService<TProductService>();
   await productService.AddProduct(shopId);
}
```

---

This gets slippery very quickly. You hinted that `AddProduct` is not a void, but returns a particular object. That's fine, you can make `IProductService` itself generic

```
public interface IProductService<TProduct>
{
    TProduct AddProduct(Guid shopId);
}

public interface IProductAService : IProductService<ProductA> 
{ 
  //specifics to service A
}
public interface IProductBService : IProductService<ProductB> 
{ 
  //specifics to service B
}
```

But now you need to also pass the product type to the generic method, as I said - it gets slippery quickly (but maybe it'll do!)

```
public static async Task AddNewProducts<TProductService, TProduct>(Guid shopId) 
                               where TProductService : IProductService<TProduct>
{
   var productService = IoC.Services.GetService<TProductService<TProduct>>();
   var added = await productService.AddProduct(shopId);
   // Note "added" is of type TProduct
}
```

I call this situation "Generic hell". You are better of rethinking your design!

Comment: Thanks, what if the method AddProduct needs to return a specific type based on the generic service? Lets say ProductAModel or ProductBModel, how can I implement that?

Comment: @user65248 Rethink your design. You're going down the wrong path!

Comment: I see what you mean, that makes sense! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async Task AddNewProducts<T>(Guid shopId) where T : IProductAService, IProductBService
```

The problem with that line is that you're requiring `T` to implement both interfaces at once, not just one of them. You haven't even gotten to the errors that will spring up when you try to call this function, because presumably your class won't implement both.

Which leads me to question why you think you need to constrain your `T` like this. The only usage of `T` is to call `Services.GetService<T>()`, so the only constraint on it should be exactly the constraints that function requires, which are definitely not your two interfaces.